# How do you initialize a vector within a class?

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, initialization

```
class Suduko
{
private:
    vector<vector<string>> board;
public:
    Suduko() : board(9, vector<string>(9, ".")) {}
}
```

Is this the only way to do it?

I've tried initializing it right where board is defined with `vector<vector<string>> board(9, vector<string>(9, "."));` but that doesnt work.

I also tried:

```
Suduko()
{
   board(9, vector<string>(9, "."));
}
```

and

```
Suduko()
{
   board = board(9, vector<string>(9, "."));
}
```

inside of the constructor and those didn't work either. So am I limited to initializing the vector to the way I did in the first example (which did work)? Or is there another way I can do it?

Comment: `vector` isn't special. Look up how to initialize any data member and you'll have your answer.

Comment: Vectors are for cases where you need dynamically resized arrays. How large do you envision your Sudoku field to grow at runtime? Also, can different rows grow separately? Seriously, this is one case where a simple 9x9 array is called for.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt This is an exercise in 2D vectors, I understand a 2D array would work more appropriately here.

Comment: You have away that always works, and you don't like it? Why?

Answer (score 3):

Here are listed some ways to initialize the vector

```
class Suduko
{
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> board { 9, std::vector<std::string>( 9, "." ) };
    //.....
};

class Suduko
{
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> board = 
        std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>( 9, std::vector<std::string>( 9, "." ) );
    //.....
};

class Suduko
{
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> board;
public:
    Suduko() : board( 9, std::vector<std::string> (9, "." ) ) 
    {
    }
};

class Suduko
{
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> board;
public:
    Suduko() : board{ 9, std::vector<std::string> (9, "." ) } 
    {
    }
};

class Suduko
{
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> board;
public:
    Suduko()
    {
        board.assign( 9, std::vector<std::string> (9, "." ) ); 
    }
};
```

Comment: The specific issue is that C++ tries to make any declaration outside of a function body of the form:

Type name(anything here);

into a function declaration. You can even see this with a simple declaration like:

int i(4);

Use one of the initializer forms Vlad posted above instead.

Answer (score 0):

To get your other attempts to work, you must use:

```
board = vector<vector<string>>(9, vector<string>(9, "."));
```

You can also use:

```
board.resize(9);
for (auto& v : board)
{
    v.resize(9, ".");
}
```

Comment: I like the second method, thank you for sharing. Is the first seen as bad practice?

Comment: @gdagger The second could possibly be faster because it doesn't create a temporary vector, I'm not sure.

Comment: @NeilKirk The speed benefit is quite small, unless you create 10000000 Sudokus each second. Readability is more impotent here. Less code = easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: @АндрейБеньковский It doesn't matter in this case but could if the technique is generalized to other projects.

Comment: @NeilKirk Compilers, processors and operating systems do so much work under the hood that it's impossible to speak about speed without actual benchmarking (except obvious cases). Your solution *might* be faster, but the only way to prove it is to do an experiment (create 10000000 sudikus in a loop).

Comment: Besides: "We should forget about small inefficiencies, say 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that **critical** 3%. A good programmer will not be lulled into complacency by such reasoning, he will be wise to look carefully at the critical code, **but only after that code has been identified.**" Donald Knuth.

Comment: @АндрейБеньковский He asked for the differences between the two so I answered. I already agreed it doesn't matter in this case. I don't need you to quote books for me.